# Permission Denied When Granting "GRANT" Privilege

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

On MySql I am able to create new users and grant them the normal data and structure privs, but when it comes to granting the GRANT priv, it throws a permissions error.

What could be causing this? Since my account is able to grant all of the other ones.

Server version: 5.6.51-log - Source distribution

Comment: As the default `root` user?

Comment: No, this is as the user the server admin set up. @tadman

Comment: Maybe they set it up with missing permissions.

Comment: @tadman That was my thought, but its strange that i can grant all the permissions EXCEPT that.

Comment: [`GRANT OPTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html) is a specific privilege that might have been overlooked, or deliberately omitted.

Comment: Run `SHOW GRANTS` when connected as your user. If it does not include the GRANT OPTION that tadman mentions, then you don't have privilege to grant privileges to other users, even if your user has that privilege.